# LEFT JOIN gets heavy as the number of records in the second table increases

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to run a `SELECT` query using `LEFT JOIN`. I get a `COUNT` on my second table ( the table on the right side of `LEFT JOIN` ). This process becomes slightly heavy as the number of records on the second table goes up. My first and second table have a one-to-many relationship. The second table's `CampaignId` column is a foreign key to the first table's `Id`. This is a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT a.[Id]
       ,a.CampaignId
       ,a.[Inserted] AS 'Date'
       ,COUNT(b.Id) AS 'Received'
  FROM [CampaignRun] AS a
  LEFT JOIN [CampaignRecipient] AS b
           ON a.Id = b.CampaignRunId
  GROUP BY 
           a.[Id], a.CampaignId,a.[Inserted]
  HAVING 
           a.CampaignId = 637
  ORDER BY 
           a.[Inserted] DESC
```

The number `637` is an example for one the records only.

Is there a way to make this query run faster?

Comment: HAVING is usually for aggregate function conditions. Put your a.CampaignId = 637 in the WHERE clause instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-select to calculate Received:

```
SELECT a.[Id]
       ,a.CampaignId
       ,a.[Inserted] AS 'Date'
       , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CampaignRecipient] AS b
          WHERE a.Id = b.CampaignRunId ) AS 'Received' 
  FROM [CampaignRun] AS a
  WHERE a.CampaignId = 637
  ORDER BY a.[Inserted] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You have unneed `HAVING` clause here, which you can move to `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT a.[Id]
       ,a.CampaignId
       ,a.[Inserted] AS 'Date'
       ,COUNT(b.Id) AS 'Received'
  FROM [CampaignRun] AS a
  LEFT JOIN [CampaignRecipient] AS b
  ON a.Id = b.CampaignRunId
  WHERE a.CampaignId = 637
  GROUP BY a.[Id], a.CampaignId,a.[Inserted]
  ORDER BY a.[Inserted] DESC
```

Also ensure that you have index on foreign key in `[CampaignRecipient]` table on `CampaignRunId` column. It's considered a good practice.